# Swift: Label unwantedly changes position

Tags: ios, swift, label, constraints, tableview

I have a `tableView` with `tableViewCell`. The cell contains three labels. When you edit an existing cell (by tapping it) or create a new one (by tapping a "plus"-button) you see a new `viewController` where you can change the content of those three labels.

All of this works fine, but when you edit (or add) a second time and save it, the first label magically changes it position (it moves down and to the left). If you close the app and reopen is, everything is at the right position again.

I just cannot understand why this is happening. The labels are inside a stack, have constraints and everything.
Does anyone have any idea? Or did anyone have a similar problem and was able to solve it?

*Thank you very much!*

Comment: I tried to imagine your code, couldn't. please share your code with us so we can try to help

Comment: Sounds like a problem with autolayout in your first label. Share your code to try to help you!

Comment: I just solved my problem. I deleted the label and recreated it. Now everything works just fine